# Unity Scene is too dark with HDRP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just installed HDRP for Unity HDRP, and I was Following Brackey's Tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12gkcdLc77s&feature=emb_logo until When he fixes the shaders. but while his is perfect, mine is not, as you can see here: [Scene is to dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiGyB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do u have a lightsource (directional light)
2. try putting the intensity of the lightsource higher